# Compare all NSStrings with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsstring

In my app are categories and in the categories are cell that contains information. The user can add a category and in a category the user can add a cell with information.
You can change the style of the cell with information with a `UISwitch` that sets a `NSString` to `@"ON"` or `@"OFF"` and the with a if statement do I check if the NSString is equal to `@"ON"` or `@"OFF"`. This all is saved in Core Data.
Now I want when **all** the cells with information in a specific category has the `NSString` `@"ON"` that the style of the categorycell change.
I can change the style, but I don't know how I can compare if **all** the `NSString`s are equal to `@"ON"`.

Can anyone help me?

**Edit:**
I use two entities (one for the categories and one for the cells with information).
In the entity for category is a attribute with the name `donelist` and the type is a string.
In the entity for the information is a attribute with the name `doneinfo` and the type is also a string.

The goal is to change the style (dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier) if all the information in the category is set to `@"ON"`.
I mean with style that the color is changed.
I had do this with an identifier, but that is not the big problem.
The problem is that I don't know how I can check if all the information in a category is done (the NSString is set to `@"ON"`).

Comment: Say something about your model...thanks

Comment: It has two entities (one for the categories, one for the cells with information). Did you mean this?

Comment: I mean you need to provide a description of the entitie(s) you are using. Please edit your question and add the details there.

Comment: Furthermore, if possible explain better your goal. I don't understand what you want to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: @Luuksweb: Did my answer help? Please tell me if you need more help with it. - Otherwise please don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark outline to the left of the answer.

Comment: I apologise for the late answer. I have write a comment under your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `cat` is a *Category* object and `cells` is the to-many relationship from *Category* to *Cell*, then you can get all cells of `cat` with "doninfo == ON" using

```
NSPredicate *onPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"doneinfo = 'ON'"];
NSSet *onCells = [cat.cells filteredSetUsingPredicate:onPredicate];
```

and you can test if all cells of this `cat` object are "ON" with

```
[cat.cells count] == [onCells count];
```

A different option is to compute

```
NSSet *onOff = [cat.cells valueForKey:@"doneinfo"];
```

- If all cells of `cat` are "ON", this gives a set with exactly 1 element "ON".
- If all cells of `cat` are "OFF", this gives a set with exactly 1 element "OFF".
- If some cells are "ON" and some are "OFF", this gives a set with 2 elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I have tried this in the `viewWillAppear` from the category view.
`NSPredicate *onPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"doneinfo = 'ON'"];
    NSSet *onCells = [cat.cells filteredSetUsingPredicate:onPredicate];`
`if ([cat.cells count] == [onCells count]) {
        NSLog(@"Cat is done!");
        UIAlertView *alertDone = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Cat is done" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertDone show];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Cat is NOT done... :(");
    }`

Comment: But every time a load the view I get a alert (also when everything is selected off or when some information cells are selected off). :(
`Cells` is the relationship.

Comment: I forgot to say that it also is when there no cells in it.

Comment: When there are no cells in the category, then `[cat.cells count]` and `[onCells count]` are both zero, so you will have to check that separately. For the other cases, I recommend to set a breakpoint and check the values of `cat.cells` and `onCells`.

Comment: I saw if there is no list the alert is also showing. I think there is another problem...

Comment: @Luuksweb: Adding `NSLog(@"cells: %d, onCells: %d", [cat.cells count], [onCells count]);` to your code should help to find the problem.

Comment: I have tried some things with the code and it works! There is only one problem and that is that I want a minimum to the count, because I have also one `else-if statement` if it is `0` that there nothing happens, but there is also one with `[cat.cells count] == [onCells count]`. How can I set a minimum of one to `[onCells count]` or `[cat.cells count]`?

Comment: @Luuksweb: I am sorry but I do not understand your last question. Is `[cat.cells count] >= 1 && [cat.cells count] == [onCells count]` what you are looking for?

Comment: I mean that I want that there is a minimum of one for the `@"Cat is done!"`, if I don't do this the `NSLog` is also showed when there are no cells in the category. Eg.: a user add a new category and the category contains no cells with information, the `NSLog` and `UIAlert` also showed. So I want to add an extra condition (there is a minimum of 1 cell in the category). I hope you understand it now (and yes I know it, my English is not so good).

Comment: @Luuksweb: I think I have answered that in my last comment: `[cat.cells count] >= 1 && [cat.cells count] == [onCells count]`

Comment: Thank you! Everything works as I want! Thank you for all the assistance that you give me! :)